# How to check for functions which have no callers in the whole project?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

How to check for functions which have no callers in the whole project?
I have turned these flags on: Unused Functions, Unused Values, Unused Variables in xCode, but it did not work.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because Xcode doesn't look for **Objective-C and Swift methods**, Xcode looks for **C functions** instead.

Actually, there is no an efficient approach to do this with Xcode. You can try to find occurrences of those specific fields and methods using *project find* tool and comment or change access level of those fields and methods to compile errors. If you try to use one of the last one approaches, the fact of your project build successfully doesn't means you made your clean up correctly, KVC or `@selector` aren't detected in compile time, because it is accessed dynamically in run time.

I know [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) have this as default and other useful tools to makes the code better.